# Ex1_5 test error during PETSc make all test

Tags: testing, petsc

I am installing PETSc on Ubuntu 16.04 to later on build [CrunchTope](https://github.com/CISteefel/CrunchTope.git). The installation goes fine using the process defined on the PETSC website. When I run `make all check`, I get a positive reply that the tests were successful.

`make all check`:

[image]

I then run the `make all test` command and it fails at one of the examples (`tao_constrained_ex-1_5`).

`make all test`:

[image]

I tried re-running the test and re-configuring the PETSc installation but to no avail. Can you please guide how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as images. Copy the actual text and put it into a code block.

Comment: As the PETSc tag on SO is not super active, you might get help faster using the [PETSc users mailing list](https://petsc.org/release/community/mailing/). Feel free to answer your own question here if you find an interesting answer.